# How to redirect all subdomains do one domain in Apache config file without specifying domain name?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, httpd.conf, regex

I want to make general rule for all my domains, so I don't have to specify each of them individually.

I have these two lines in my Apache config file:

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

Now I have more domains pointing to the same directory. And I would have to repeat these 2 lines for each domain. I was trying to edit this condition and rule, but with no success to make them general to any domain without actually specifying domain name. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

To redirect everything except `www.domain.com` (since that would be a loop) to `www.domain.com`, you'd want something like this:

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```